# Literales mal traducidos en PopUp de: Formulando una buena pregunta

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, traducciones

Hace un rato me percate de que el `PopUp` de ayuda a la hora de realizar una buena pregunta tiene textos que están mal traducidos.

He buscado en preguntas más recientes pero no veo que nadie haya publicado una pregunta, de como se podría reportar este `bug`, ¿alguien que sepa como notificar este podría orientarme de como se hace?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguramente tiene que ver con las traducciones que aun no se han aplicado...

Comment: Entiendo que este PopUp no es nuevo, ¿puede ser que directamente se pierdan las traducciones? El enlace de @padaleiana es una solución de cara a corregir un bug de este tipo, pero ¿es habitual que esto ocurra?

Comment: Al parecer, ambas no han recibido ninguna sugerencia de edicion hasta ahora. https://es.traducir.win/strings/15582 - https://es.traducir.win/strings/15588

Comment: No consideramos bugs a la falta de traducciones. Si no quieres traducirlas vos mismo, se encargara la comunidad. Gracias por avisar! Tene en cuenta que se pueden pasar cosas por alto, porque no vemos todos los carteles que salen...

Comment: Vale, más que nada ha sido curiosidad, y aprender un poco más de la comunidad, la verdad es que no son textos complicados para traducir, pero prefiero abstenerme para evitar algún posible error.

Comment: @gbianchi No veo en donde diga que no quiere traducirlas, seguro desconoce el uso de es.traducir.win y ya. A mi me pasaba lo mismo antes, creo que hice temas en meta por el mismo motivo.

Comment: @Excorpion no quise decir que no quisiera, si no que si no quisiera... o sea.. no implique que no tenga ganas, si no que no tenia porque hacerlo...

Comment: @gbianchi esto en el comentario: ***Si no quieres traducirlas vos mismo, se encargara la comunidad***; me parece que el usuario hace su mejor esfuerzo avisando de la falta de traducción, esto no implica que deba o que no quiera traducirlo, incluso puedo apostar que ni siquiera sabe que la comunidad es la que se encarga de eso o que existen herramientas. En algunas regiones / paises de Centro America lo que acabas de hacer puede sonar un poco rudo. saludos.

Comment: @gbianchi ahh, se entendia de otra forma...

Comment: @Excorpion exacto... XD

Comment: OP contesto mi comentario sin haberse sentido ofendido. No entiendo porque el resto se ofende, cuando OP no se ofendio, y luego cuando me preguntaron por el comentario explique claramente lo que quise decir. Esto no es español neutro, es español de todos lados, y se presume que lo que se dijo, se dijo con amabilidad, y si surge alguna duda se aclara. No se como escribirlo de forma tal que no parezca "rudo", cuando lo que dije fue que no tenia porque encargarse en persona de hacer las traducciones.

Comment: Igual como nota ya lo tradujo Excorpion y ya acepte sus traducciones...

Comment: Tal y como afirma @gbianchi, en ningún momento he visto una ofensa por su parte, se ha explicado bien y no me lo he tomado a mal su comentario.

Comment: Si, eso fue aclarado por el chat igual ;)

Comment: fue un comentario / sugerencia ... simplemente apliquen lo que dice gbianchi: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59409151#59409151

Comment: @gbianchi mira que el popup que sugiero en otro post de meta ya existe. XD solo hace falta agregarle la traduccion... en que momento deja de aparecer, solo sale la primera vez o hasta qye llegue a X cantidad de rep???